# How to block until thread pool is empty... with an unknown number of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Say I have a thread pool of some kind.  I submit one thread to it and it goes on its merry way.  I want to block the main thread until the pool is empty/all threads have finished, without busy waiting preferably.

But the thread can create and add its own threads to the pool (a quantity that is unknown beforehand)... so it is important that the pool may continue to accept and process threads normally while the main thread blocks.  The context, though it doesn't matter: I'm performing a graph search.

I have found *so many* almost-solutions:

- Executors can wait for threads to finish, but don't allow new threads to be added while it does so.
- CountDownLatch is incredibly close, but can't be incremented when a new thread is created.

Likewise there are many threads on this topic, but they all involve programs that know how many threads are being created beforehand.  I actually find it odd that it's a question not asked more often (or at all)!

Comment: Does this _need_ to be threads or are we talking work units which can be contained in a Callable?  If the latter, you should separate the work from the mechanism parallelizing the work.

Comment: My program searches a graph.  Whenever it reaches a vertex with more than one unvisited neighbour, it creates one or more extra threads to continue down them.  At dead ends or goals, the threads stop.  It starts with just the one thread for the starting vertex, and the main thread sits there and wait for the search to complete.  

That's where a thread pool or similar construct seems to make sense to me.  Each new thread is managed or added to the pool and the work is done when there are no threads running.

Comment: I can do this with a concurrent container or semaphore and busy wait easily, but if the main thread were to just block outright until no search threads are running, that seems like the more efficient solution to me?

Comment: @Tom It sounds well suited for a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Comment: @assylias That it does! Thanks -- put it down as an answer and I'll tick it :)

Comment: @Tom that's a little too short for an answer and don't have time to elaborate now. I'm sure somebody will post something more detailed (if not feel free to post your own answer). See also: [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) - although it says it has been updated for Java 8 and I'm not sure what changes have been made (not many I would have thought).

Comment: try to think in terms of data flow, rather than in terms of control. When a vertex processing is finished, it is passed to, say, referencing vertices. When all referenced vertices are processed, the referencing vertex is considered processed and is passed to its referencing vertices etc. Then wait the start vertex to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tom commented, [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) seems adequate: tasks that are added to the pool can spawn additional subtasks in the pool. To block until all tasks have been processed, you use `awaitTermination`.

Note that tasks and threads aren't the same thing. You could of course have one thread per task, but that would be inefficient, especially if there are many tasks. Internally, the pool allocates a given numbers of threads, that will try to execute the tasks that are pending as quickly as possible.

When a task needs to spawn subtasks, you can use

- `invokeAll( listOfTasks )` -- the method blocks until all subtasks have completed. The subtasks are executed in the pool of the "parent" tasks.
- `getPool().execute( aTask )` -- you can queue subtasks without blocking a well.

The first option is the idiomatic way to use ForkJoinPool. It enables parallel divide and conquer algorithms (see the example in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)). But the second option should work as well if a task spawns subtasks but doesn't care about their results.